# Leela Chess Zero: how large is the probability vector in the output layer?

Tags: conv-neural-network

Recently, Alpha Zero and Leela Chess Zero are based on the idea that a given chess position s can be given both an evaluation number, as well as a probability vector for the next move. This number and vector are the output neurons of a CNN. My question is: given that different chess positions s and s' have a different amount of legal chess moves, how is this probability vector structured if it doesn't have a fixed size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability vector for the next move (called the policy) is based on the total number of possible moves from any chess position, which is a fixed number. AlphaZero used 4672 possible moves (stated [on page 13 of the paper](https://cdn.chess24.com/GzFl-Z4-SVWO-mC9rL6XhQ/original/mastering-chess-and-shogi-by-self-play.pdf)); Leela Chess Zero uses about 1800 possible moves (you can see them all [listed in the bitboard.cc](https://github.com/LeelaChessZero/lc0/blob/master/src/chess/bitboard.cc) code).